# Uniqueness of multiple columns on data entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to validate the uniqueness of the data i enter so there is no duplicates at all.

**Model**

```
 class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
      validates :Devtype, presence: true
      validates_uniqueness_of :Nic1mac, :scope => [:Nic1mac, :Nic2mac, :Nic3mac, :IBmac, :SN], :allow_blank => true
      validates_uniqueness_of :Nic2mac, :scope => [:Nic1mac, :Nic2mac, :Nic3mac, :IBmac, :SN], :allow_blank => true
      validates_uniqueness_of :Nic3mac, :scope => [:Nic1mac, :Nic2mac, :Nic3mac, :IBmac, :SN], :allow_blank => true
      validates_uniqueness_of :IBmac, :scope => [:Nic1mac, :Nic2mac, :Nic3mac, :IBmac, :SN], :allow_blank => true
      validates_uniqueness_of :SN, :scope => [:Nic1mac, :Nic2mac, :Nic3mac, :IBmac, :SN], :allow_blank => true
    end
```

This is what I saw recommended in similar questions but it is not working for me. I input my first data in the "Nic1mac" field. When I create another entry and try to populate the "Nic1mac" field with the same data it stops me as is expected. But when i populate the "Nic2mac" field with the same data that is in the "Nic1mac" field it allows for the record to be created without any error. Thus I have a duplicate mac address in different fields. Another issue is if i create a new record and enter the same data in the "Nic1mac" and the "Nic2mac" it allows the record to be created without noticing that the data in the "Nic1mac" is the same in another record.

**Example**

Record one-

Nic1mac = 1234

Record two-

Nic2mac = 1234 (no error is shown and record is allowed to be created even though the data is the same as in record 1 Nic1mac)

Record three-

Nic1mac = 1234 (error comes up as expected)

Nic2mac = 1234 (allows for record creation even though data is the same as record 1 and 2)

I would also like to prevent duplicate data from being entered at the record creation step.

**Example**

Record one creation-

Nic1mac = 1234

Nic2mac = 1234

I want an error to arise that does not allow me to create the record because of the duplicate data being inputed into two different fields. If more clarity is needed or and more information or code please let me know and I will do my best to provide it.

Comment: Why do you need to write `validates_uniqueness_of` statement 5 times? You are using same attrs, so I think you need it only once.

Comment: I want each field to be validated against every other field so there is no data replication. This is why i have it 5 times. If there is another way of doing it or i did it wrong i am all ears.

Comment: Well, you did. scope does slightly different thing than you expected. It does not compare values between columns. It validates uniqueness of combination of values from all of the columns. I feel I'm not clear enough, but here is a good example: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of

Answer (score 0):

You could store all your macs in different class Mac (just one), so you'll have to validate uniqueness of just one column:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :Nic1mac, class_name: 'Mac'
  has_one :Nic2mac, class_name: 'Mac'
  has_one :Nic3mac, class_name: 'Mac'
end

Class Mac < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :asset
  validates_uniqueness_of :mac_addr
end
```

Comment: by creating this class I would also have to make its own model, view and controller for it? or would it just require tweaks to my asset model,view,and controller? @IvanSelivanov

Comment: you definitely need to create a new model, because model means database table to store data. And you can do without everything else, just modify asset's model and controller. May be helpful to read this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for @aealvarez3